# Closed form solution $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{H_n}$

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers, wolfram-alpha

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{H_n}$$
Where $H_n$ denotes the nth harmonic number.

I am a little confused because WolframAlpha says [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bm%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28-1%5Cright%29%5E%7Bm%7D%7D%7BH%5Cleft%28m%5Cright%29%7D&assumption=%7B%22FunClash%22%2C+%22H%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22HarmonicNumber%22%7D) that it is approximately $-0.626332$ but when I type it in [slightly differently](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2CSum%5BDivide%5B1%2Cm%5D%2C%7Bm%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D), it gives $-0.550242...$ I tried putting these numbers in the inverse symbolic calculator to find possible closed forms but I didn't get anything that seemed useful. I may just be overlooking something.

Also, how would I go about solving this by hand? I know it is equivalent to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}}$ but I can't tell if that actually helps with anything. I've played around with it in Desmos a little and can't seem to figure anything out.

Comment: it's pretty disgusting that the estimates are off by 0.07 when you type the same function one using $H_n$ and one using $\sum_k^n 1/k$

Comment: Where is this sum from, or are you just playing around symbolically and seeing if you can solve this?

Comment: Note that in your second attempt, WA gives the answer as a complex number (with imaginary part very close to zero).  Now obviously the imaginary part should be exactly zero, but the fact that it is there at all suggests that your second way of typing the expression has (somehow) prompted WA to use a different approximate method of calculation.  For more details, you will probably need to find someone who knows a **lot** about the internal workings of WA.

Comment: If you ask for more and more digits in the second case, the value will keep changing. Sometimes larger, sometimes smaller. I paired up consecutive terms so that all terms are negative and found that the absolute value of the sum is larger than $0.575$. I approximated the error using an integral giving something like $0.05$ for the tail, so the value $-0.626\ldots$ seems more realistic.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429058/is-there-a-closed-form-for-the-alternating-series-of-inverse-harmonic-numbers?

Comment: @Snared I am just playing around symbolically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Euler–Boole summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Boole_summation),
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{H_n }}}  \sim \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{H_n }}}  + ( - 1)^N \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{E_{2k} }}{{4^k (2k)!}}\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}^{2k} }}{{{\rm d}x^{2k} }}\frac{1}{{\psi (x + 1/2) + \gamma }}} \right]_{x = N} } 
$$
as $N\to +\infty$. Here, $E_k$ denotes the [Euler numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers), $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant), and $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). Taking $N=100$ and keeping the first $5$ terms of the asymptotic expansion, I obtained $-0.626332482737912\ldots$ for the value of your sum.

Comment: As an alternative: [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)'s `sumalt(n=1,(-1)^(n-1)/sum(k=1,n,1.0/k))` produces $$0.62633248273791235470865726622798606395\dots$$ (confirming your result). The approach is [here](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/exp-math-9/fulltext.pdf) (I didn't compare the complexities).

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you for the confirmation and the link to the paper. I guess my approach is far from being efficient.